# Why do they portray characters with beard/eyebrows not matching their hair?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did they make characters like Gendry to have blonde beard when he has black hair?

Or Daenerys to have black eyebrows, when she has silver hair.

Comment: Hi there. I've taken the liberty to edit out the question about Jon Snow, as it seemed to be a different situation than the Gendry/Daenerys one; I think the post would then have been too broad (because it's two different questions). If I misunderstood, you're welcome to [edit] your question to clarify :) and if it is indeed a different question, like asking about why they changed his hair from the books' depiction, you can ask it as a new one - see [ask] and the [help] for more info about how this site works. Cheers!

Comment: The Jon Snow question is an entirely different question based on his lineage. But that's answered by the fact that you have Lyanna Mormont who had black hair and it would appear that that trait carried through to Jon.

Comment: Also, in the real world, it's not uncommon to have hair color mismatch. My brother has brown hair and a red beard. I have auburn hair and blond eyebrows.

Comment: Whilst the dupe is about Dany specifically it does a good job of answering the general case to that I feel it’s enough to adequately answer the broad case.

Comment: I've got brown eyebrows and transparent hair

Comment: Blonde with really dark eyebrows and a beard that's always been all over the place here. We deserve our on-screen representation too!